# AWS EC2 hangs ipV4 based connections on port 3005 but works for different ports

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Deployed a Node js application to EC2 instance with 3005 as the port, it failed to respond to ipv4 based connections while it worked for the ipv6 ones. But when I change the port to something else, like 3100, it works fine? This is super strange, anyone can venture a guess as to why?

Comment: Have you checked your security groups are allowing inbound connection on port 3005?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I did, and they do!